# My live updater crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, function, variables, setinterval

I have a live updater for a variable but it keeps crashing the browser, any other methods I could do a live updater in Javascript would be very much appreciated!

Here's my code;

```
var health;
function decrease() {
    health = health - 2;
}

function mainUI() {
    setInterval(decrease(),30000);
    if (health <= 5) {
        document.write("Below 5!");
    } else {
        document.write("Over 5!");
    }
}

mainUI();
setInterval(mainUI(),1000);
```

The whole idea of it is to refresh the variable data without refreshing the browser, any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`?  You should *not* be using that.  Also, you want to do `setInterval(mainUI,1000);`.  Don't include the `()` here.  You want to pass the function, not its return value.

Comment: What would you suggest I use instead of `document.write()`?

Comment: I think you'll want to make a variable to hold the `decrease` timeout as well, otherwise you will exponentially spawn them.

Comment: Use JS DOM methods, like innerHTML.

Comment: @user1028642: Update the `.innerHTML` property of a DOM element.

Comment: @zero298: Good catch!  Each time `mainUI` is called, he's making *another* interval for `decrease`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <span id="spanHealth"></span>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var health;
function decrease() {
    health = health - 2;
}

function mainUI() {
    var msg = (health <= 5 ? "Below 5!" : "Over 5!");
    document.getElementById("spanHealth").innerHTML = msg;
}

setInterval(mainUI, 1000);
setInterval(decrease, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small page that will give you buttons to poison, cure, and revive a `div` using `setInterval`

[image]

**Style**

```
 #health{
    width: 170px;
 }
 .normalHealth{
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
 }
 .lowHealth{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
 }
 .dead{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
 }
```

**Script**

```
 var health = 10;
 var poisonTimer;
 var healthDiv;

 function loseHealth() {
    health -= 2;
    updateUI();
 }

 function givePoison() {
    poisonTimer = setInterval(loseHealth, 1000);
 }

 function giveAntidote() {
    clearInterval(poisonTimer);
 }
 function kill() {
    health = 0;
    healthDiv.className = "dead";
    giveAntidote(healthDiv);
    document.getElementById("revive").disabled = false;
    updateUI();
 }
 function revive() {
    health = 10;
    healthDiv.className = "normalHealth";
    document.getElementById("revive").disabled = false;
    updateUI();
 }

 function updateUI() {
    healthDiv.innerHTML = health;

    if (health > 4) {
       healthDiv.className = "normalHealth";
    }
    else if (health > 0) {
       healthDiv.className = "lowHealth";
    }
    else {
       kill();
    }
 }

 function main() {
    healthDiv = document.getElementById("health");
    document.getElementById("poison").addEventListener("click", givePoison);
    document.getElementById("cure").addEventListener("click", giveAntidote);
    document.getElementById("revive").addEventListener("click", revive);
 }

 window.onload = main;
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Health Bar</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="health" class="normalHealth">10</div>
      <button id="poison">Poison</button>
      <button id="cure">Cure</button>
      <button id="revive" disabled>Revive</button>
   </body>
</html>
```